# Improve World of Warcraft in WINE? (GTX 660)

Tags: 13.04, drivers, nvidia, wine

Before you say anything, I know I'm not going to get the same performance under WINE as in Windows.

Now, I've been getting really poor performace with running WoW: Mists of Pandaria, and it's not just 10 or 20 fps less, it's literally around 100-200 fps or more.

I've tried running it with D3D and OpenGL, and the only difference is D3D has a lot higher options for some reason.

When running in Windows I get about 80 fps with ALL performance settings maximized / set to the highest value possible. When running in WINE I get about crash / 30-60 fps on the absolute lowest settings.

Here's all the PC info:

Motherboard: GIGABYTE 970A-UD3

GFX: Zotac GTX 660

CPU: AMD FX 6300 3.5GHz

SSD: Samsung 840 120GB

PSU: Corsair CX 600M

RAM: Corsair Vengeance 8GB

Driver: nvidia-310

WINE: 1.4

Comment: Do you have nvidia drivers installed?

Comment: I'm using the nvidia-310 driver.

Comment: Anyone? I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the game with this line:

```
__GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 WINEDEBUG=-all wine wow-64 -opengl
```

Notice the double underscore at the start.. This activates all your cpu kernels, will bring up your fps to the roof.